# Setting the position on a button in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, row

I just wrote a code that creates a window (using TKinter) and displays one working button.

```
b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
```

But i would like to have multiple buttons underneath this one.

How do you set the row and column of the button? 
I tried to add `row = 0, column = 0,` but that would not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

astynax is right. To follow the example you gave:

```
MyButton1 = Button(master, text="BUTTON1", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=0, column=0)

MyButton2 = Button(master, text="BUTTON2", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton2.grid(row=1, column=0)

MyButton3 = Button(master, text="BUTTON3", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton3.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Should create 3 row of buttons. Using grid is a lot better than using pack. However, if you use grid on one button and pack on another it will not work and you will get an error.

Comment: I recommend not to prefer one over the other -- learn the strengths of each, and use the right tool for the job. Pack is remarkably powerful and easy for a certain class of layout problems, as is grid. They each can more easily solve some problems than the other.

Answer (score 51):

Causing a widget to appear requires that you position it using with what Tkinter calls "geometry managers". The three managers are [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm). Each has strengths and weaknesses. These three managers are implemented as methods on all widgets.

**grid**, as its name implies, is perfect for laying widgets in a grid. You can specify rows and columns, row and column spans, padding, etc.

Example:

```
b = Button(...)
b.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
```

**pack** uses a box metaphor, letting you "pack" widgets along one of the sides of a container. pack is extremely good at all-vertical or all-horizontal layouts. Toolbars, for example, where widgets are aligned in a horizontal line, are a good place to use pack.

Example:

```
b = Button(...)
b.pack(side="top", fill='both', expand=True, padx=4, pady=4)`
```

**place** is the least used geometry manager. With place you specify the exact x/y location and exact width/height for a widget. It has some nice features such as being able to use either absolute or relative coordinates (for example: you can place a widget at 10,10, or at 50% of the widgets width or height).

Unlike `grid` and `pack`, using `place` does not cause the parent widget to expand or collapse to fit all of the widgets that have been placed inside.

Example:

```
b = Button(...)
b.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
```

With those three geometry managers you can do just about any type of layout you can imagine.

Comment: Well explained! But how can I use all of them together?

Comment: Does `x` and `y` mean coordinate inside the window or outside it too?

Comment: @CoolCloud: the coordinates are relative to the inside of the master window.  You can set the `bordermode` attribute to determine whether the values include the border or not.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm):

```
btns = [
    (lambda ctl: ctl.grid(row=r, column=c) or ctl)(
        Button(text=str(1 + r * 3 + c)))
    for c in (0,1,2) for r in (0,1,2)]
```

result:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

Comment: -1 Your code instantiates the buttons but your variable `btns` is a list of None...