# Positioning Button in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive researched my question here, [Python Tkinter buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370357/python-tkinter-buttons), and here, [Setting the position on a button in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927234/setting-the-position-on-a-button-in-python)

Sadly, I'm still stuck.  I'm making a game inspired by the game angry red button.

I'm attempting to have a second button placed next to a first one, which python autonomatically places in the top center of the screen.

When I run the code pasted below, no additional button appears. See screen shot below, 
[image: Screen Shot]

Here is my attempt using pack (seen toward the bottom of the code).

```
from tkinter import *
s = 0
def kill():
  cnv.color('red')
def talk():
  global s
  if s == 0:
      cnv.create_text(100,20,text='why, hello there!', font='Times')
      s += 1
  elif s == 1:
      cnv.create_text(100,40,text='my name is Phill!', font='Courier')
      s += 1
  elif s == 2:
      cnv.create_text(100,60,text='why are you clicking me?', font='Times')
      s += 1
  elif s == 3:
      cnv.create_text(100,80,text='that kinda hurts...', font='Arial')
      s += 1
  elif s == 4:
      cnv.create_text(100,100,text='ok, what do you want?', font='Courier')
      s += 1
  elif s == 5:
      cnv.create_text(145,130,text='seriously, stop that!', font=('Arial',28), fill='red')
      s += 1
  elif s == 6:
      cnv.create_text(100,160,text='...', font='Times')
      s += 1
  elif s == 7:
      cnv.create_text(100,180,text='You know what?', font='Courier')
      s += 1
  elif s == 8:
      cnv.create_text(100,200,text="You wanna go?", font='Courier')
      s += 1
  elif s == 9:
      cnv.create_text(105,220,text='OK!!!', font=('Arial',28), fill='red')
      v = Button(tk, text="Death",command=kill)
      v.pack(side="right")
      l = Button(tk, text="Death",command=kill)
      l.pack(side="left")
      s += 1
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="Phill",command=talk,width=10,height=10)
btn.pack()
cnv = Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=700)
cnv.pack()
```

Any ideas how to make this work with pack, or perhaps with grid?

Answer (score 0):

use `.pack(side=LEFT)` for example, or whatever side you want.
I suggest experimenting with this.

Comment: Thank you!  I got it to work using pack as you suggested.  I can position buttons top, bottom, right or left.  Now, I have the next problem, which I will create in a new thread (I'm not able to create a new button by pushing the original button)