# How to place a Tkinter widget at given coordinates in a fixed window?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it actually possible to place widgets at specific coordinates in a Tkinter window? For example, if i set up a window like so...

```
class LogInWindow(object):
def __init__(self):
    #create variables
    self.currentUser = StringVar()
    #create the window and frame
    self.LW = Toplevel()
    self.LW.title('Login')
    self.LW.geometry('310x100-500+300')
    self.LW.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.LWFrame = ttk.Frame(self.LW)
```

Creating a fixed window 310 pixels wide and 100 pixels high. How would I then place a button at say x=120,y=62?

I've explored the pack and grid documentation but cannot seem to find anything useful.

Comment: You can, but it's rarely a good idea. Tkinter is very good at arranging widgets within a window. Why do you think you need to place a widget at an explicit coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the less well known [`place` geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

In your case you'd simply create the button and `place` it at the coordinates you want.

```
b = tk.Button(self.LW,text='Button')
b.place(x=120,y=62)
```

The reason [people typical avoid 'place'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072375/why-does-people-say-dont-use-place) is that it isn't automatically responsive to things like design changes or window resizes in the same way that pack and grid are.

You might be better off using `relx` and `rely` and the `anchor` options to express the position in terms of fractions of the window rather than specifying an absolute position to avoid some of these disadvantages.

Comment: Does `x` and `y` mean the coordinates inside the window or the screen coordinates?

Comment: I think it's the coordinate inside the window. It's been a while since I used Tkinter though so I'm not 100% sure.