# Add text entry widget over picture in tkinter using python

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make a text entry widget over picture in tkinter using python?
The code I am using:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()
root.title('Title')
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5,show='*') # tried this line of code but it didn't worked
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("path/to/image.png"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
c = Button(text="        OK         ")
c.place(relx=0.95, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
root.mainloop()
```

It can make a button (**OK**) , why it can't make entry text widget?

Comment: you are not `pack`ing your entry.

Comment: also, don't mix geometry managers.(pack, place etc.) choose one and stick to it.

Comment: @Lafexlos really thank you, I missed that line.

Comment: @Lafexlos do you know how can I change the position of that text entry widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to *pack* the **Entry** field, just try something like:

```
E1 = Entry(root, bd = 5,show='*') 
E1.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

And customize the position and behaviour as you prefer.

Comment: How can I change position of it?

Comment: If you finally use `pack` as a geometry manager (using only one as @lafexlos suggested) then you can customize position, size, etc. of it by changing its configuration parameters. You will find more of this [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

Comment: I still didn't get how to change position of it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/LayoutsideTOPLEFT.htm) you will find some layout examples of the `pack`geometry manager, otherwise if you prefer to use another one, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937799) can help you to understand  their differences.

Comment: I got it myself.